# google maps v3 api - select location and mark it

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Currently, I am able to make map to show selected location at its center, but I am unable to mark it,,  like showing a red bulb on it.

I am using click event listener that gives marker

then:

```
options = {'zoom': 8, center: marker.latLng}
map.setOptions(options)
```

This is setting selected(clicked) location to center of map, but not showing any bulb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
options = {'zoom': 8, center: marker.latLng}
map.setOptions(options);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: map.getCenter(),
map: map
});
```

But the best aproach is the one provided by the [Google API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers):

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

// To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title:"Hello World!"
});
```

Comment: What do you mean ? You want to add new markers on click event?

Comment: I mean, as per your answer, I am able to set markers, so if I click 100 times, even though I save to db only latest one, those 100 bubbles will be visible on the map. So, clear all the red bubbles from map when a new one is selected.

Comment: The process is too simple. Based on the example above, you can use marker.setMap(null); to remove it from the map. In case you use maltiple markers, it is better to use an array, in order to assign the marker objects in it, and then to be able to remove it.

Comment: Please don't forget to upvote and/or mark as correct answer my answer if you are huppy with the information I provided to you